# Volume of irregular polyhedron

Tags: python, math, numpy, 3d

I am trying to put a method together to compute the volume of a **irregular** but otherwise convex pyhedron:
It uses triangulation to split the polyhedron into multiple sub-tetrahedrons (simplex) and calculate the volume independently, then sum up all sub-volume values.

However, I get weird results for the unit - cube below in my test. Anyone an idea where the bug resides?

```
class Simplex(object):
    def __init__(self,coordinates):  
        if not len(coordinates) == 4:
            raise RuntimeError('You must provide only 4 coordinates!')
        self.coordinates = coordinates

    def volume(self):
        '''
        volume: Return volume of simplex. Formula from http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetraeder
        '''
        import numpy

        vA = numpy.array(self.coordinates[1]) - numpy.array(self.coordinates[0])
        vB = numpy.array(self.coordinates[2]) - numpy.array(self.coordinates[0])
        vC = numpy.array(self.coordinates[3]) - numpy.array(self.coordinates[0])

        return numpy.abs(numpy.dot(numpy.cross(vA,vB),vC)) / 6.0  
'''
Old code that did not work
class Polyeder(object):
    def __init__(self,coordinates):
        if len(coordinates) < 4:
            raise RuntimeError('You must provide at least 4 coordinates!')
        self.coordinates = coordinates

    def volume(self):
        pivotCoordinate = self.coordinates[0]
        volumeSum = 0

        for i in xrange(1,len(self.coordinates)-3):
            newCoordinates = [pivotCoordinate]
            for j in xrange(i,i+3):
                newCoordinates.append(self.coordinates[j])
            simplex = Simplex(newCoordinates)
            volumeSum += simplex.volume()

        return volumeSum
'''

class Polyeder(object):

def __init__(self,coordinates):
    '''
    Constructor
    '''

    if len(coordinates) < 4:
        raise RuntimeError('You must provide at least 4 coordinates!')

    self.coordinates = coordinates


def volume(self):
    from pyhull.delaunay import DelaunayTri

    delaunay = DelaunayTri(self.coordinates,joggle=True)
    volume = 0
    for vertices in delaunay.vertices:

        coords = [self.coordinates[i] for i in vertices]
        simplex = Simplex(coords)
        volume += simplex.volume()


    return volume

coords = []

coords.append([0,0,0])
coords.append([1,0,0])
coords.append([0,1,0])
coords.append([0,0,1])

s = Simplex(coords)
print s.volume()

coords.append([0,1,1])
coords.append([1,0,1])
coords.append([1,1,0])
coords.append([1,1,1])

p = Polyeder(coords)
print p.volume()
```

Old results print outs are:

```
0.166666666667
0.666666666667
```

The values should be 1/6 for the tetrahedron (correct), but 1 for the unit cube

New results are:
    0.166666666667
    1.0

Comment: I'm not sure, but do you need to permute the other coordinates, rather than simply shifting through them?  It seems that you only calculate 4 tetrahedron volumes when should be calculating 6.

Comment: Yes, that's also my guess that I am missing permutations of the three other simplex points. Will give it a shot.

Comment: My mental example was maybe something like a (simplistic) brilliant-cut diamond if your pivot is the point; you'll never calculate the volume of the cone formed by the table to the point if you just iterate through the points on the crown in series.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Gaussian quadrature over a formula for numerical integration.  That's the way this is usually done using finite element methods.  You'd start with a unit shape in parametric space and transform it to global coordinates.

You might also consider using Green's theorem to transform a volume integral into a surface integral.  Discretizing the surface of a complex shape will be easier that way.  It lends itself especially well to complex shapes with holes.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion which might be correct, but may be little too complex. I am looking at polyhedrons returned from Voronoi 3D tessalation and have many of such rather than one big. Hence, speed is an issue here too. I need a fast and reliable algorithm aplicable to many in parallel... I'll have a look into your suggested methods, woun't hurt to look.